# Let users withdraw earnings to Paypal

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I'm looking for a Wordpress plugin(if exists) by which users can withdraw their earnings made on my website to their Paypal accounts.

Just like Freelance websites: Withdraw your earnings to Paypal

Any plugin suggestion or idea how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any readily available plugins for this, however, you could build it using the PayPal [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Just add a simple interface for the user to see their balance and trigger the payment of what they're owed, and then make a call to the Pay API to send them the payment directly when the action is triggered.

This [PHP SDK for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the [Pay request](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/templates/Pay.php) (and any other [PayPal classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/) for that matter) very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thank you! That's what i was looking for!